# Restrict user to edit only edit a certain menu

Tags: menus, user-roles, admin-menu

I'm using a plugin (User Role Editor) to take care of the user roles. This works fine, except that you can't give a user acces to only a certain menu. I have two menu's in my website. One 'main' menu and a 'secondary' menu. The plugin only allows 'edit_theme_options' which allows to edit all the menus's. I only want the user to be able to edit the secondary menu.

Comment: User capabilities are not this fine-grained in WordPress, and the UI for menus does not support differing levels of access for each menu.

Comment: Perhaps with clever use of actions/filters you could prevent the changes the user makes to a menu from saving. Maybe `wp_insert_post_data`, but do have a look at the `save_post` action to find proper hook that runs before saving actually happens.